# How do I search for a specific contact in INSendPaymentIntent (SiriKit)?

Tags: swift, ios10, sirikit

**Summary** 
Trying to code a `INSendPaymentIntent` but am having trouble differentiating between contacts sharing a similar first name. Siri seems to go in a loop right after `INPersonResolutionResult.disambiguation(with: matchedContacts)`

**Thoughts Behind The Code** 
I chose to use a contact's given name to search contacts initially since using the `INPerson` display name returns the first contact that matches the query if the user only specifies the first name. *(i.e. 'Pay Kevin $50' will automatically select Kevin Bacon over Kevin Spacey)*.

Unfortunately, using the given name sends Siri into a loop asking the user to specify the contact over and over again...

**Question** 
Is there any way of searching through contacts using a contact's first name without sending Siri into a loop?

**Code**

```
func resolvePayee(forSendPayment intent: INSendPaymentIntent, with completion: (INPersonResolutionResult) -> Void) {
    if let payee = intent.payee {
        var resolutionResult: INPersonResolutionResult?
        var matchedContacts: [INPerson] = []
        let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContacts(matchingName: (payee.nameComponents?.givenName)!)

        do {
            let searchContactsResult = try CNContactStore().unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch:[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactMiddleNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactIdentifierKey])
            for contact in searchContactsResult {
                matchedContacts.append(createContact((contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue)!, contact: contact))
            }
        } catch {
            completion(INPersonResolutionResult.unsupported())
        }

        switch matchedContacts.count {
            case 2 ... Int.max:
                resolutionResult = INPersonResolutionResult.disambiguation(with: matchedContacts)
            case 1:
                let recipientMatched = matchedContacts[0]
                print("Matched a recipient: \(recipientMatched.displayName)")
                resolutionResult = INPersonResolutionResult.success(with: recipientMatched)
            case 0:
                print("This is unsupported")
                resolutionResult = INPersonResolutionResult.unsupported()
            default:
                break
        }

        completion(resolutionResult!)
    } else {
        completion(INPersonResolutionResult.needsValue())
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "using the given name sends Siri into a loop asking the user to specify the contact over and over again", does that mean you are hitting case 0 of the switch statement?

Comment: @rocky nope it's case 1. Log prints that the recipient was matched but Siri asks the question again.

Comment: Are you sure that recipientMatched is of type INPerson?

Comment: @rocky yup, it might have been a bug with Siri

Comment: @cyril have you found solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Siri will ask to confirm the name of the person whenever you return this:

```
completion(INPersonResolutionResult.needsValue())
```

Or this:

```
completion(INPersonResolutionResult.disambiguation(with: matchedContacts))
```

In this case, I think it's way more likely that it goes into the loop because you kept returning the second result (`INPersonResolutionResult.disambiguation`). Which means your query in this line kept returning 2 persons or more:

```
let searchContactsResult = try CNContactStore().unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch:[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactMiddleNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactIdentifierKey])
```

I would suggest you to debug that line and see if you ever gives Siri back this value:

```
INPersonResolutionResult.success
```